# Python Loop iteration with replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the time series array like

```
[[1539841080000,None],[1539841140000,None],[1539841200000,1.07609359e+08],
 [1539841260000,None],[1539841320000,None],[1539841380000,None],
 [1539841440000,None],[1539841500000,None],[1539841560000,1.07613162e+08],
 [1539841620000,None],[1539841680000,None],[1539841740000,None],
 [1539841800000,None]]
```

and would like to have the result like

```
[[1539841200000,1.07609359e+08],[1539841260000,1.07609359e+08],
 [1539841320000,1.07609359e+08],[1539841380000,1.07609359e+08],
 [1539841440000,1.07609359e+08],[1539841500000,1.07609359e+08]]
```

So when ever first value appears in the array that should be carried forward to other array values too till the next value arises and also have to drop the initial null values with the time series

Also I would like to generate the delta values from the above time series data.
Is it possible to get the delta from new value - old value [1539841200000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], [1539841260000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], [1539841320000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], [1539841380000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], [1539841440000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], [1539841500000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], with less number temp variables in code

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What is this `null` you refer to?

Comment: null refers to zero or no value

Comment: I would like to drop the initial null values and whenever the 1st value arises in the list, that needs to copied on the next timeseries data as well till the 2nd value arieses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by `null` you are referring to `None`.

```
data = [[1539841080000,None],[1539841140000,None],[1539841200000,1.07609359e+08],[1539841260000,None],[1539841320000,None],[1539841380000,None],[1539841440000,None],[1539841500000,None],[1539841560000,1.07613162e+08],[1539841620000,None],[1539841680000,1.07613162e+08],[1539841740000,None],[1539841800000,None]]

prev_val = None
new_data = []

for item in data:
    t, d = item
    if d is None and prev_val is not None:
        new_data.append([t,prev_val])
    elif d is not None:
        prev_val = d
        new_data.append(item)

print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[[1539841200000, 107609359.0], [1539841260000, 107609359.0], [1539841320000, 107609359.0], [1539841380000, 107609359.0], [1539841440000, 107609359.0], [1539841500000, 107609359.0], [1539841560000, 107613162.0], [1539841620000, 107613162.0], [1539841680000, 107613162.0], [1539841740000, 107613162.0], [1539841800000, 107613162.0]]
```

Comment: that's really useful.

Comment: Also can I get the delta from new value - old value   [1539841200000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
[1539841260000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
[1539841320000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
[1539841380000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
[1539841440000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
[1539841500000, 107613162.0 - 107609359.0], 
with less number temp variables in code

Comment: I don't understand. You have to be more specific. How do you decide new value and old value. Explain in detail by editing your question